# isin check on column datatypes returning false

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, series, isin

I have a dataframe which prints the following information when info() method is called:
[Output of info on dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT4Ne.png)

When i run the following line to identify columns with int and float data types,

discrete_features = X_train.dtypes.isin([int, float])
print(f"Discrete Features: {discrete_features}" )

i get the following output:

Discrete Features: id         False
gravity    False
ph         False
osmo       False
cond       False
urea       False
calc       False
dtype: bool

Even if i try with the below modified line, i still get the same output. discrete_features = X_train.dtypes.isin([np.int32, np.float32])

why are the column datatypes not getting properly identified

Expecting discrete_columns to have names of all columns with int and float type to be correctly identified as True